# It's just black or It's just dark

Tags: phrase-request

> Nothing visible through the windshield. It's just black.

I take my car into a forest, the car battery goes down. Outside it's so dark. I wrote the above sentence to describe what I see though the windshield. Now my confusion is whether "It's just black" is a natural way a native speaker say it, or if they'd just say "It's just dark".

Answer (score 2):

A native speaker would probably say:

> I can't see a thing! It's ***pitch black*** outside.

Comment: Perhaps so, although I don't find anything wrong with the original. It could work in a story. The first segment is a fragment (_There's nothing visible through the windshield_ would fix that), but, in a larger context, that might be fine; writers use fragments all the time.

Comment: You could also say ***pitch dark***

Comment: @J.R. Yes, I like to use the fragment, the complete sentence which doesn't look good for story.